# Having trouble with simple count primes smaller than n problem

Tags: c++, primes, heap-corruption

I've been attempting leetcode problem 204 (count primes smaller than n), and I keep on getting a "heap-use-after-free" error. My solution is below. I've added some print statements to get some idea of what is happening but it isn't really helping.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int countPrimes(int n) {
  if (n < 2) return 0;

  vector<int> primes;
  primes.push_back(2);
  for (int m = 3; m < n; m++) {
      cout << "m = " << m << endl;
      for (auto it = primes.begin(); it < primes.end(); it++) {
         cout << *it << ", ";
      }
      cout << endl;
      bool prime = true;
      for (int d : primes) {
          cout << "d = " << d << endl;
          if (m % d == 0) {
              prime = false;
              break;
          }
      cout << "end m = " << m << endl;
      if (prime) primes.push_back(m);
      } 
  }
  return primes.size();
}

int main() {

  cout << countPrimes(9) << endl;

}
```

Print outputs:

```
m = 3
2,
d = 2
end m = 3
m = 4
2, 3,
d = 2
m = 5
2, 3,
d = 2
end m = 5
d = 0
exit status -1
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong. It's making me think I have some fundamental misunderstanding of what I'm doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
bool prime = true;
for (int d : primes) {
    ...
if (prime) primes.push_back(m);
}
```

You can't use a range based for loop on a vector, if the loop also changes the size of the vector. Range based for loops depend on iterators to the vector, and all iterators to a vector are invalidated if an element is added to the vector.

Of course you really meant to write this code

```
bool prime = true;
for (int d : primes) {
    ...
}
if (prime)
    primes.push_back(m);
```

which is fine because the vector is modified after the loop, not during the loop.

The lesson is be really strict with how you indent code. Misplaced lines of code are easy to spot if you always indent correctly.

Comment: Thank you! I was losing my mind there. I think you're right about needing to be strict about indentation. This isn't the first time I've made this mistake.